# Texlive on Mac: I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'. ...hadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta}

Tags: errors, texstudio, tikz-arrows

I seem to have problems compiling a latex document which i ported from my ubuntu machine to my mac machine..

I am using texstudio, and I am for some reason getting this error:

```
I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'. ...hadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
```

Due to this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,shadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
```

The document compiles on my ubuntu machine and how no idea on what could be the cause of the error?...

Comment: Did you use the MacTeX package to install TeX Live? If so, what does `which pdflatex` return? Can you compile other documents using 'relive studio'?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I just edited the post..

Comment: texstudio is an editor. It has nothing to do with LaTeX, it is just a convenient way to write LaTeX code and call LaTeX. Since it comes this far you have installed some LaTeX installation on your Mac. We need to know what exactly you installed as the answer depends on it.

Comment: I would mean i installed it using homebrew.. brew install texlive.. 
That should have handled everything.

Comment: Homebrew often  causes problems. Consider installing mactex 2016 and using that instead. Yes it is a little weighty but it is super easy to install and contains everything provided for texlive including the files you are missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running the latest versions, try updating all of your packages through Tex Live Utility (check if `pgf` and `tikz` have pending updates). If that doesn't work try upgrading [MacTex](https://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Also try typesetting from Terminal to see if your editor is playing tricks on you and maybe provide us with an example that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .. I just edited my post.. I haven't used mactex..  I am using texstudio.. not texlive

Comment: As @daleif said, Tex Studio is just an editor. You must have an instance of LaTeX installed on your Mac and most likely you used MacTex to do so (and that includes Tex Live Utility to manage packages). To check if that's the case go to  > System Preferences and open the Tex Distribution pane. It should tell which version of TexLive you installed.

Comment: @Maurizio: But there is no longer a TeX Distribution pane (with current versions of MacTeX and OS-X).

Comment: @JohnCollins Really? Then I guess mine is still there from previous versions. Thanks for pointing that out. @dfh in that case `pdflatex --versions` should give you plenty of information.

Comment: I do have a tex distribution pane in system preference, but it keeps popping up with errors.

Comment: @Maurizio `pdflatex --versions` doesn't show anything...

Comment: @Maurizio using `locate`i can find pdflatex here: `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex`
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex`

Comment: @dhf You are using TexLive 2013. Upgrade it by installing MacTeX-2016. You can get rid of the preference pane, read [here](https://tug.org/mactex/multipletexdistributions.html) "Selecting the Active Distribution". 

(Sorry, there was a typo, it's `pdflatex --version` and not `versions`)

Comment: So.. Installed mactex-2016. 
Via tex live utility updated the packages, and changed the default texlive version from 2013 to 2016.  Still same problems in texstudio..

Comment: and `-bash: pdflatex: command not found`

Comment: @dhf It looks like the folder where `pdflatex` is symlinked (`/Library/TeX/texbin/`)  isn't in your system's `PATH` variable. Can you check that? Did you remove TexLive-2013 before installing MacTex-2016? Also try `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --version` to make absolutely sure TexLive-2016 is active.

Comment: `$ /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04`

Comment: How should i check whether pdflatex is symlinked?

I don't think i removed the 2013.. it is still possible to choose it in tex live utility..

and the output of `pdflatex --version` can be seen above.

Comment: Go to TeXstudio preferences (`cmd + ,`),  select the `Commands` tab on the left and make sure `pdflatex` links to `/Library/TeX/texbin/` - [this](http://imgur.com/gm8GVYi) is how it looks on my Mac. To see if `PATH` includes the Tex dir run `echo $PATH` in the shell, it most likely doesn't.

Comment: yep seemed to have fixed it.. they were all sat to 2013.. changed them all to `/Library/TeX/texbin/` and it compiled.. thanks for help.. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after installing TeX Live 2016 (via MacTeX) make sure you haven't messed up the PATH variable. First, /Library/TeX/texbin should be in your PATH variable (run `echo $PATH` to check). Second, run `which pdflatex` and see that the correct pdflatex is found (/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex). If either of those are not true you need to edit your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` and place the line

`export PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:"$PATH"`

as the last line of the file. That should make sure that `which pdflatex` finds the correct distribution.

Next, make sure you DON'T have any of the TeX related shell variables defined.

Finally, you may very well have to edit the TeXStudio Preferences so that it finds the correct TeX Live distribution. Read the information at <http://www.tug.org/mactex/sierra.html> and, especially, the `Updating For El Capitan and Sierra` document l